# Obtaining an NSArray of Core Data properties

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Consider a Core Data database containing Elements where each Element has a property called `symbol`, and the question is the most succinct method of obtaining an `NSArray` of each of the symbols.  This can be accomplished with something along the lines of

```
-(NSArray*)symbolsInDatabase {
  ENTRY_LOG;

  NSError* err;

  NSFetchRequest* request   = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Element"];
  request.resultType        = NSDictionaryResultType;
  request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"symbol"];

  NSArray* arrayOfDictionaries = [self.database.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];
  NSMutableArray* symbols = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[arrayOfDictionaries count]];

  for (NSDictionary* d in arrayOfDictionaries) {
    [symbols addObject:[d objectForKey:@"symbol"]];
  }

  EXIT_LOG;
  return symbols;

}
```

Yet there is a nagging feeling I'm missing something, and that I can be using `-(NSArray*)filteredArrayUsingPredicate` in some clever manner rather than iterating over the array of dictionaries and extracting the object for the `symbol` key.

Any thoughts on how to make this cleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the valueForKeyPath selector:

```
NSArray *symbols = [arrayOfDictionaries valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.symbol"];
```

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'allValues' - that's a selector on NSDictionary.

Comment: Edited to reflect the correct selector is valueForKeyPath, see also http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html for a description of Collection Operators.  Upvote upon edit approval.